# Souler: other meanings than "to get drunk"?

Tags: anglais, expressions, sens, registre-familier

My French penpal has introduced this verb to me with some more “slang” contexts and I'm still trying to figure out good translations to English to better understand the use of it. I'd appreciate any explanations on general usage of this verb in these kind of contexts.

Here are some examples that I need help with:

> J'espère qu'elle va pas me souler !
>
> Arrête de me souler !
>
> Putain tu me soules !
>
> Je suis soulée.
>
> Ça me soule.

Comment: Right in http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souler A2b.

Comment: Remarque (et ajout de mots-clés pour les recherches), on voit souvent ce verbe orthographié *soûler* ou *saouler*, la variante *souler* introduite par réforme de 1990 n'a pas vraiment pris.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Evpok has it right with his comment: all is well explained in the article if you want the French definition of the term. To clear up things,
we can try some possible translations (I tried to vary on purpose but it's quite arbitrary. Just giving an idea):

- J'espère qu'elle va pas me souler.

  > I hope she won't get on my nerves.
- Arrête de me souler !

  > Stop pissing me off!
- Putain tu me soules…

  > Damn, you're boring me to death…
- Je suis soulée.

  > I'm cheesed off with it. / I'm fed up with it. (pick your prefered version)
- Ça me soule.

  > This really sucks.

Comment: I'm American, I've never heard of "I'm cheesed off with it." Is that British for something like I'm annoyed? Otherwise, thank you! This has really helped me.

Comment: @BryanDenny: [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions) is the place to ask about English usage.

Comment: @BryanDenny Laure is right... but I guess a web search should clear up things rather well, there are some informative results.

Comment: *fed up* is probably more common.

Comment: I don't think "boring me to death" corresponds to "tu me soules". What you said before was correct, "you're pissing me off" or "you're getting me upset/on my nerves" fits better.

Comment: @FrenchKheldar It depends mainly on the context, and these are just arbitrary examples, precisely to show the different possible meanings of *saouler*. And *boring someone to death* certainly IS an existing meaning of *saouler quelqu'un*.

Comment: We'll respectfully disagree then. If I want to say someone is boring, I would use some other slang, like _tu es chiant_ (although not exactly a good fit as too close to _souler_ in that case) or expressions involving _rasoir_ or _mortel_ (like _ennui mortel_). One concept behind _souler_ is the overdose of activity/chatter, which seems counter to the idea of boredom. The other concept as shown in the latter example is the one of _ennui_, but, to me at least, not in the sense of boredom, but in the sense of fatigue/obstacle/hazard.

Answer (score 2):

*souler quelqu'un* means "to get someone drunk". *Se souler* means "to get drunk".
The other meaning which is much more frequent is "to piss someone off".